# How to get the type of the user in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, authentication, phpmyadmin

I want the code to check if the current user category is `admin` or `superadmin`, it will show the edit panel

```
 @if (Auth::user()->category=='admin'||Auth::user()->category=='superadmin')
    <td class="center">
      <a href="{{ route('Order.edit', ['id'=>$order->id ]) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm custom"> 
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> EDIT</a>
    </td>
```

else, it will display message like this

```
@else
   <td class="center">
     <b><p>This is only for admin</p></b>   
   </td>
```

I have table `user` and in the table I have `category`. 
But it looks like it cannot check for the condition correctly. 
It always display message even the user category is `admin` or `superadmin`

Comment: Can you share your User model?

Comment: protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'type',
    ]; protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

protected $fillable = [ 'name', 'email', 'password', 'type', ]; protected $hidden = [ 'password', 'remember_token', ];

In your user table you mentioned "type" and in your condition you are checking "category" if i am not wrong then change your "category" to "type" in Your Condition like mentioned below

@if (Auth::user()->type=='admin'||Auth::user()->type=='superadmin')

Answer (score 0):

Auth::user()->category=='admin'  X

Auth::user()->category->name=='admin' , or the column name where 'admin' is .

Comment: It is not working. It just the same to what I have done

Comment: can you show me the structure of category table ?? and user table..as well